# Why am I getting a Segmentation Fault in my program?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I was trying to do this program when I noticed in my points3D method that something was causing a Segmentation fault and I don't know what caused it. The goal of this program is to test out 4 different methods and try to get a certain answer. I thought I mostly did it right until I noticed my method ~point3D. Although I fixed this problem, I cant find any problem why this would happen.

```
//You only need iostream, no other header files are allowed
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Code for part 1
class point2D {
    int x, y;
      char* label;
public:
    int getX(){
      return x;
    }
    int getY(){
      return y;
    }
   char* getLabel(){
      return label;
    }
    void setX(int a){
      x = a;
    }
    void setY(int b){
      y = b;
    }
    void setLabel(char* g){
      label = g;
    }
    virtual void show(){
      cout << "The point data is " << "(" << x << "," << y << "," << label << ")" << endl;
    }
    point2D(int x, int y, char * label){
      this->x = x;
      this->y = y;
      label = nullptr;
      setLabel(label);
    };
    ~point2D(){
      if(label != nullptr){
        delete[] label;
      }
    };

};

//Code for part 2
class point3D : public point2D {
protected:
  int z;
public:

  int getZ(){
    return z;
  }
  void setZ(int c){
    z = c;
  }
  void show(){
    cout << "(" << getX() << "," << getY() << "," << z << "," << getLabel() << ")\n";
  };
  point3D(int a, int b, int c, char * l) : point2D(a,b,l) {
      z = c;
  };
  ~point3D();
  
};
/*
//Code for Part 3
class node {
public:
  point3D* data;
  node* next;
  static int counter;
  void show(){
    if(data != nullptr){
      data->show();
    }
  }
  node(){
    data = nullptr;
    next = nullptr;
  }
  ~node(){
    if(data != nullptr){
      delete[] data;
    }
  }
};

//Code for Part 4
class linkedList {
    node* head;
public:
  bool empty() {
        return head == nullptr;
    }
    int size() {
        int c = 0;
        node* it = head;
        while (it != nullptr) {
            c++;
            it = it->next;
        }
        return c;
    }
    bool push(point3D* np) {
        node* nn = new node();
        nn->data = np;
        return push(nn);
    }
    bool push(node* nn) {
        nn->next = head;
        head = nn;
        return true;
    }
    bool append(point3D* np) {
        node* nn = new node();
        nn->data = np;
        return append(nn);
    }
    bool append(node* nn) {
        if (head != nullptr) {
            node* it = head;
            while (it->next != nullptr) {
                it = it->next;
            }
            it->next = nn;
        }
        else {
            head = nn;
        }
        return true;
    }
    void show() {
        node* it = head;
        while (it != nullptr) {
            it->show();
            it = it->next;
        }
    }
    linkedList() {
        head = nullptr;
    }
  ~linkedList(){
    node * it = head;
    node = nullptr;
    while(it != nullptr){
      
    }
  }
};

int node::counter = 0;
*/
int main() {
    int testMode;//Determines the test to be executed
    std::cin >> testMode;
    switch (testMode) {
    case 1:{
        //1) Test part 1
        point2D * p12D = new point2D(12, 24, (char*)"test 1");
        p12D->setX(25);
        p12D->setLabel((char*)"Landing Zone A");
        p12D->show();
        delete p12D;
        break;
    }
   case 2: {
        //2) Test part 2
        point3D* p13D = new point3D(12, 24, 36,(char*) "test 2");
        p13D->setY(50);
        p13D->setLabel((char*)"Landing Zone B");
        p13D->show();
        point2D* p22D = dynamic_cast<point2D*>(p13D);
        p22D->show();
        std::decay_t(&p13D);
        break;
    }
    /*
    case 3: {
        //3) Test part 3
        node* nn = new node();
        std::cout << node::counter << std::endl;
        delete nn;

        nn = new node();
        std::cout << node::counter << std::endl;
        point3D* p23D = new point3D(48,60,72,"Landing Zone C");
        nn->data = p23D;
        nn->show();
        
        delete nn;

        break;
    }
    case 4: {
        //4) Test part 4
        linkedList* myList = new linkedList();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            node* nn = new node();
            point3D* p3D = new point3D(12*i, 24*i, 36*i, "Landing Zone ");
            myList->addNode(p3D);
        }
        myList->show();

        point3D* p3D = new point3D(12 * i, 24 * i, 36 * i, "Landing Zone ");
        myList->insertNode(p3D, 1);
        myList->show();
        delete myList;
        break;
    }
    */
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

I have tried multiple things and got a error that was void operator delete(void*, std::size_t)’ called on unallocated object ‘p13D.

Comment: What is the input that reproduces the issue?

Comment: You appear to be unfamiliar with the Rule of Three which is: If you write a non-default version of any one of the three special member functions `destructor`, `copy constructor`, `copy assignment operator`, you need to write all of them. You have a destructor so you need to write the code for your copy construction and assignment. (If you are on C++11 or newer, this is instead the Rule of Five, with the added special member functions `move constructor` and `move assignment operator`.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.  Fix the warnings.  Don't use casts.  Fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
new point2D(12, 24, (char*)"test 1");
```

There is a reason why you were forced to make this explicit ugly cast. String literals are `const char *`. They are created by your compiler, and are constant objects.

```
    void setLabel(char* g){
      label = g;
    }

    point2D(int x, int y, char * label){
      this->x = x;
      this->y = y;
      label = nullptr;
      setLabel(label);
    };
```

After all is said and done, the constructor ends up storing the pointer into `label`.

```
    ~point2D(){
      if(label != nullptr){
        delete[] label;
      }
```

And the destructor happily tries to `delete` something that was never `new`ed. There's your crash.

In C++ you are required to `delete` only something that was created in dynamic scope, with `new`. This didn't happen here, hence undefined behavior, and crash.

This is C++, not C. In C++ we use `std::string` to deal with strings, which correctly handles and properly manages all memory allocation for you, so you don't need to worry about these low level details.  Replacing everything with `std::string`s will avoid this entire issue, altogether. And, as an extra bonus, no more ugly casts.

Comment: We can't use std::string in this project. We can only use char* strings(or C strings) in this case because it is required to for the class I am currently in.

Comment: Sounds like you need to switch classes to a different class, where real C++ gets learned.